# How to put a scrollbar in tkinter, without using frames? (Python)

Tags: python, scroll, tkinter, scrollbar

I really dislike using frames, and so I would like to put a scrollbar by my buttons without using frames. It is just one button being repeated with different text:

```
x = 0
    yPos = 0.3
    try:
      for button in range(0,100):
        chemResourceButton = Button(root, text=resources[x] + "-" + descriptions[x])
        chemResourceButton.place(relx=0.5, rely=yPos, anchor=CENTER)
        x = x + 1
        yPos = yPos + 0.2
```

Thanks for help

Comment: If you dislike using frames, then change library. Frames are really essential to structure and design your GUIs.

Comment: @Rinzler my GUI is fine without using frames until this point. How do I make a frame? I have seen tutorials but they all involve functions and self. Thanks for your help

Comment: Frames are mainly used to group widgets. For example, you have a GUI, and you want to divide it in 2 parts, top and bottom, you might want to use one Frame for the top (with all its widgets) and one Frame for the bottom. See [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm), it might help a little bit.

Comment: Frames are mainly used to group widgets. For example, you have a GUI, and you want to divide it in 2 parts, top and bottom, you might want to use one Frame for the top (with all its widgets) and one Frame for the bottom. See [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm), it might help a little bit.

Comment: @Rinzler so, how would I apply a frame to my code and put a scroll bar in it?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you don't want to use frames?
They're pretty simple to use.
If you wanted to insert a scrollbar you could use pack method pretty easily to do it.

Just declare something like this.

```
master=Tk()
LeftFrame = Frame(master)
RightFrame = Frame(master)

LeftFrame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
RightFrame.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
```

This would essentially split the screen in half allowing you to have a scrollbar inside the frame on the right hand side, although you may want to play with the configuration a bit, I'd take away the `fill="both", expand=True` options for a scrollbar, and allow you to have the body of your screen on the left.

Using gird method could work out for you too but it allows less control over the exact positioning of objects on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't use them, because when I did all the frame's widgets all went in to the top of the screen and I couldn't use them.

Comment: How would I put widgets in there? I use place for my widgets, and my frame will need to take up the whole y, and the center of the screen

Comment: If you read through this link it should explain .pack() configuration
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm

Comment: If this question has been answered can you please close it